# Graph php problems displaying data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problems displaying my data on my graph. The issues happens when I try to select my data. Here is the code:

```
    $sel_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j")-$day, date("Y"));
    $sel_tag = date("Y.m.d",$sel_timestamp);
    mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
    $result = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT *, COUNT(tracking.user_id) AS user_views FROM user, tracking WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id AND tracking.timestamp = $les_tag GROUP BY $user_id ORDER BY user_views LIMIT 1");      
    $usercheck = mysql_result($res, 0, 0); 
    $Userstats = $usercheck;  

    $bar[$bar_nr]=$Userstats; 
    $bar_title[$bar_nr] = date("j.M.Y",$les_timestamp);

    if (date("j")-$day == 1) $bar_mark = $bar_nr;
    if ( date("w", $les_timestamp) == 6 OR date("w", $les_timestamp)== 0) {$weekend[$bar_nr]=true;}
    else {$weekend[$bar_nr]=false;}

    $bar_nr++;
```

The data displays as is all the bars with one visitor. I believe the issue happens at SELECT here is the code:

```
    $result = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT *, COUNT(tracking.user_id) AS user_views FROM user, tracking WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id AND tracking.timestamp = $les_tag GROUP BY $user_id ORDER BY user_views LIMIT 1");      
    $usercheck = mysql_result($res, 0, 0); 
    $Userstats = $usercheck;
```

How can I fix my code so I can display my graph correctly?

Comment: Might be nice to get some sample data and expected results, but I can already tell you: 1) you're not going to get useful results, because you do a cross-join with `tracking` and `user` (no join criteria - please always explicitly qualify your join, which would make this more obvious). 2) All columns except the `COUNT(...)` will be 'random' for data from the tracking table.  3) I find it unlikely that `=` is the comparison operator you want for a timestamp. 4) default sort order is _ascending_. 5) You're (probably) wide open to SQL Injection - please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query feature have been deprecated
http://www.php.net/function.mysql-db-query

The another issue with you query is you are trying to group the data but limiting query result to 1(Limit 1)